# Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o52.fit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run Logistic Regression using Apache Spark 2.4.5 on Arch Linux. When I run

```
train_df = pipeline.fit(train_df).transform(train_df)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a5d69091f01c> in <module>
----> 1 train_df = pipeline.fit(train_df).transform(train_df)

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    107                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    108                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 109                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    110                     transformers.append(model)
    111                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

/opt/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/apache-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    334             raise Py4JError(
    335                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 336                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    337     else:
    338         type = answer[1]

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o52.fit
```

I also get the following warnings

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16...'the class']
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/Hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar...'the class']
util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large.
```

I'm not sure if the warnings are the reason why my code isn't running.